# Software Licensing method with Public key Encryption

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, software-distribution

I am working on a method for licencing a software for distribution.

All the .exe distributed will have a public key.
Public key will be same for all distributions, which will be used to encrypt licencing information and generate a licence file.

The distribution will be supplied with a private key(serial key) which will be used to run the software.
Private key will be different for all distributions.

can anyone suggest any algorithm to which can encrypt with a single public key
and decrypt with different private key.

[Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24125/multiple-private-keys-for-single-public-key) is the link which i found similar to this topic but cant figure out how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in your link by Artjom;

> Let's say multiple recipients have (a different) private key and all
>   of them can decrypt data encrypted with the same public key. You
>   should ask yourself, how can the different private keys be generated
>   to arrive at the same public key, but where all the recipients
>   wouldn't know the private key of each other.

Actually, he tries to say, this construction would be impossible.

And again in your link Panco noted; the questions;

> I suspect you need to think more about the security goals (and
>   nongoals) of the system. The cluster head sends a message; who must be
>   able to read the message (e.g. the intended recipient)? Who must not
>   be able to read the message (e.g. random third parties)? Who don't you
>   care whether they can or cannot (e.g. the cluster head itself)? Also,
>   this is an ad hoc network; how do nodes join the cluster? Is there
>   some sort of introduction protocol (where keys can be exchanged)?

This is your solution;

> Depending on the answers, a purely symmetric system may be the Right
>   Thing.

Comment: Thanks, This seems in need to look for a different approach.